Android - Gradle management of artifacts with different flavors
I have an Android Module that wraps an external library provided by an .aar file.
This lib is imported as follow:
configurations.maybeCreate("default") artifacts.add("default", file("ExternalLibrary.aar"))
Everything works properly, but I'd like to switch library according to a specific flavor.
Is there a way to do this?
I appreciate your help
I tried to migrate module to a library and then I defined flavors

Switch library? Switch to what? You have another .aar file to use in the place of this external library?

@SimonJacobs yes. In the same Android module I have 2 .aar files and I need to import only one on the basis of a specific flavor.

The Android plugin automatically creates dependency configurations for each flavor of your app (docs).
So if you have a couple of product flavors, default and special, configured like so (using Kotlin DSL):
android {
    flavorDimensions += "type"
    productFlavors {
        create("default")
        create("special")
    }
}

That configuration will add the configurations defaultImplementation and specialImplementation, so I can add dependencies to those for use in the corresponding flavor source sets (also recognised by the plugin in (using this example src/default and src/special):
dependencies {
    "defaultImplementation"(files("path/to/defaultAar.aar"))
    "specialImplementation"(files("path/to/specialAar.aar"))
}

If those libraries share an API of some kind that you want to do different things in different flavors of the app, you'll need to extract the shared classes and interfaces of that API into a separate dependency and place that in a shared dependency configuration eg implementation and access it from, the corresponding source set (in this case, main).

I tried you solutions but I have the following error building app:
`The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.3.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :myModule:
      - defaultDebugApiElements

      - specialDebugApiElements`


It looks like a downstream consumer of your module doesn't know whether to pick up the new default or special flavor of your module. You need a strategy for deciding which. Eg this question has some recommendations in the answers
